# Android Intent to Google Maps Navigation using Google Place id (not by Coordinates or Address)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, navigation

From Google, 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation,

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

I can successfully open Google Maps in navigation mode, however, since in previous page of my app, I use google autocomplete feature and get a `Place`. And there is `placeId` for each place. The problem is how to use to above turn-by-turn navigation method but using `placeId` instead of address or coordinates(since placeId is more accurate than other).

Comment: I think the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation) is pretty clear on that: *`q`: Sets the end point for navigation searches. This value can be latitude, longitude coordinates or a query formatted address.* That said, I don't see why directions to a place id would be any different or less accurate or whatever if you used the place coords.

Comment: i also believe that it should not be different. But the fact is that it will get to incorrect building/ location after testing a lot. The error rate is quite high. So I raise this problem.

Comment: Why haven't you shared a single example then?

Comment: if you need draw path or direction between your current location and your destination, see this uri API with placeId (i dont use from turn-by-turn navigation):                                                  
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=27.1750151,78.0421552&destination_place_id=ChIJbf8C1yFxdDkR3n12P4DkKt0"));
        startActivity(intent);

Comment: my client would like to open turn-by-turn navigation directly

Comment: You can use [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action) with your intents. The Google Maps URLs in directions mode support both origin place id and destination place id. The turn-by-turn navigation is also supported.

Answer (score -1):

Taken from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide):

The api endpoint has two parameters as you can see in the first line - `query` and `query_place_id`. `query` does not need to be accurate if you have place id, since place id is so much more exact, so you can see I simply entered a filler string (the parameter is still required in the api). Add your place id in the endpoint and set the intent like shown, which is the proper intent to open Google Maps navigation on an android phone.

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=qwerty&query_place_id=" + loc_id);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Answer (score -2):

Seems there is no possibility to use directly `placeId` int turn-by-tyrn navigation intent, but anyway you can pass coordinates of `Place` to navigation:

```
Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);

if (place != null) {
    LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
    String strLatitude = String.valueOf(latLng.latitude);
    String strLongitude = String.valueOf(latLng.longitude);

    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(String.format("google.navigation:q=%s,%s",strLatitude, strLongitude));
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    startActivity(mapIntent)
}
```

Comment: navigation is only 70% correct, so need to use placeId